# css two column layout problem

Tags: css

[image of css layout that i want](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/9898/problemcss.jpg)

Thas is the layout that i want to accomplish, kind of, I am having troubles having thos two columns together but the first one longer than the second, and getting them inside the white div.

so..

div1: is just a div with auto height and black bg
div2: the same as div1 but white bg
div3 and div4 are divs with auto height too, and grey bg at some point div 4 could be longer than div 3 or the other way around, these columns can increse in height therefore div1 and div2 should stretch
div5-8 are just images.

I am able to get this positioning of the divs, but they wont stay into the white div (when i float left div 3)
they show up like div 3 was on top of the white and black divs, and if i make it longer it stretches more than the div1 and 2

Or I can also get them all inside the white div, but without floating left div4 which doesnt help =/

I know has to be some positioning problem, but I've tried some combinations and they wont work, at this point I am not using any position relative or anything.

help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div3 and div4 need to be `float`ed...

div5 - div8 need `clear:both;`

```
    <style>
      div                          { overflow:hidden; }
      div.3, div.4                 { float:left; }
      div.5, div.6, div.7, div.8   { clear:both; }

    </style>
    <div class="1">
      <div class="2">
        <div class="3"></div>
        <div class="4"></div>
        <div class="5"></div>
        <div class="6"></div>
        <div class="7"></div>
        <div class="8"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

That is the jist of it, you fill in the rest...

Comment: thank you so much, the overflow:hidden, made it happen!, not sure what it does but ill investigate, thanks again!

Comment: Yeap, overflow is funky when you don't specify it. I usually set it to hidden. Rarely do I want something to be visible outside of it's container...

Answer (score 1):

Go for the [960 Grid System](http://www.960.gs). You should be able to achieve the mockup above in a few minutes by using that 960 framework.